# Unmet dependencies, install -f looks scary

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64-bit

I tried to install Lazarus (1.4.4) by downloading the `.deb` files and using `sudo dpkg -i`. However I think it tried to install them in the wrong order and I now get "unmet dependencies" errors whenever I use `apt-get`. Even trying to remove the offending package doesn't work as apt-get claims it's not installed.

```
\> sudo apt-get remove lazarus  

Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
Package lazarus is not installed, so not removed  
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:   The following packages have unmet dependencies.    lazarus:i386 : Depends: libgtk2.0-dev:i386 (>= 2.6.0) but it is not going to be installed    
                Depends: fpc:i386 (>= 2.6.4) but it is not installable or  
                         fp-compiler:i386 (>= 2.6.4)   ...
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

(same results with `sudo apt-get autoremove`, and `dpkg --purge --force-depends lazarus` also claims that `lazarus` is not installed)

When I try `sudo apt-get -f install`, I'm prompted to do some very scary stuff including removing 304 packages, some of which look rather important (e.g. `ubuntu-desktop`), and some of which are apparently essential to my system operation (`python-minimal`, `python2.7minimal`). That seems like massive overkill to just resolve dependencies for one half-installed package.

Can anyone recommend the safest way to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think I might have fixed the immediate issue by using "sudo apt-get remove lazarus:i386" rather than just "lazarus".

Comment: Great so it is solved? Could you post an answer for this or should we close the question as final target is to install `lazarus`?